# How to use a cell's value for part of a cmd argument in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, cmd

I am trying to use a cell's value (a path, in this case) as part of a cmd argument in VBA.

My three tests to execute cmd lines from VBA.
Test1 and Test2 work perfectly, but I cannot get Test3 to work. Is this a syntax issue, or how might I otherwise get VBA to execute the line how I want it to?

Here is the screenshot for reference:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you try Range(3,1) instead?

Comment: @Tom Unfortunately that results in an error! RGA's answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quotation marks appear to be in the incorrect place for the call to perform as desired.  Change that line to `Shell ("cmd /c hostname > " & Range("A3"))` and it should work as intended

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is a syntax issue, as you enclose the command in speech marks `""` there is a break where you use speech marks within your command.

In order to get around this you need to use double speech marks within your string:

`Shell ("cmd /c hostname > Range(""A3"")")`